# jquery dropdown div not quite working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make a div drop down when someone hovers over a link. Inside the div is a login form. The following code works only in that if i hover over the link the div does appear. However when i move the mouse from the link down over the div, the div immediately retracts. Please see:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.slidedown').hide(); 
    jQuery('a.top-link-cart').hover( function(){ // enter animation

    jQuery('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate({
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        }, 600, function() { /* animation done */ });

    }, function(){ // leave animation

jQuery('.slidedown').mouseout( function() {
   setTimeout( function(){
      jQuery('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate( {
          height: '0px'}, 600, function(){});}, 200 ); // setTimeout ends here
}); // mouseout ends here
    });
});
```

All i'm trying to achieve is have the div a) stay open if the user mouses from the link to the div b)close if the user moves mouse away from link but not into div and c) close if user moves mouse out of div. I thought the .mouseout function would keep the div open so that i can at least move my mouse over it but it isn't working. Any ideas? I'd be very grateful this has been a headache to me for a week now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.hover` but `.mouseover()` instead for your first method.

Comment: thanks that makes the div stay down so i can mouse over it. Now how to make it close after those two conditions... I might make a jsfiddle for input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your `div.slidedown` inside the `a.top-link-cart`:

```
<a class="top-link-cart">Show login form
    <div class="slidedown">
        The login form HTML
    </div>
</a>
```

Ignoring standards *(block elements like `<div>` tags shouldn't really be nested inside inline elements like `<a>` tags)*, this will work because when the `div.slidedown` expands, so does the parent `<a>`.

That way, the mouseout event won't be triggered until the user's mouse leaves the `<a>`.

Comment: not sure if i can do that, the links are dynamically generated by php i can't just open a file and find some html for that link to edit.

Comment: Have a look at @heymrcarter's answer, that should work perfectly if you can edit the HTML / PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your link and the div that does the animation in another div and then apply the hover to the parent div instead of the link. This way you will still validate. For example:

```
<div class="whatever">
    <a class="top-link-cart">Show login form</a>
    <div class="slidedown">form html goes here</div>
</div>
```

and the javascript would be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slidedown').hide();
    jQuery('.whatever').hover(function(){//to show
        jQuery('.slidedown').show('effect', duration in millisecs);
    }, function(){//to hide
        jQuery('.slidedown').hide('effect', duration in millisecs);
    });
});
```

this uses the jQueryUI for the animation effects, but you could use the .slideDown() and .slideUp() methods as well if all you need is the div to slide up or down